# focusout() not working as expected (in this very basic example)

Tags: html, jquery

I'm trying to create a custom dropdown with two simple elements -- a `div` for the dropdown header, and a `div` to contain the items. When the header-div is clicked, the items-div is to be opened, and when the items-div loses focus, it is to be closed.

Code (HTML):

```
<div id="dd_header" style="width:200px;height:20px;border:1px solid gray"></div>
<div id="dd_items" style="width:200px;height:200px;border:1px solid gray">
    Item 1<br/>
    Item 2<br/>
    Item 3<br/>
</div>
```

Code (JS):

```
$("#dd_items").hide();

$("#dd_header").click(function () {
    $("#dd_items").show();
});

$("#dd_items").focusout(function () {
    $("#dd_items").hide();
});
```

**jsFiddle -- http://jsfiddle.net/FLnHG/**

For some reason, **the `focusout` event isn't firing**. What am I missing?

*(Note: Adding the `focusout` on `#dd_header` works, but that doesn't help because the user won't be able to make a selection from the items).*

Comment: can you produce this: _Adding the focusout on #dd_header works_

Comment: @Jai: Interesting catch!! I'd originally used `<input>` for the header, and it had worked (http://jsfiddle.net/FLnHG/9/). But with a `<div>`, that doesn't work too!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way:

```
$("#dd_items").hide();

$("#dd_header, #dd_items").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation(); ///<----this stops the event to bubble up at document
    $("#dd_items").show();
});


$(document).click(function () {
    $("#dd_items").hide();
});
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/FLnHG/17/)

Comment: This seems like it should ideally work, but clicking on the items menu closes it? We're planning to have multi-select in items, so it shouldn't close unless the user clicks outside.

Comment: @SNag you can try the updated one although i just hide the `#dd_items` in css

Comment: Thanks a ton! This mechanism works great and is just the behaviour I was looking for. (And thanks for showing me this interesting workaround to `focusout`!)

Answer (score 4):

add js code in ready and use mouseout

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#dd_items").hide();

   $("#dd_header").click(function () {
      $("#dd_items").show();
   });

   $("#dd_items").mouseout(function () {
      $("#dd_items").hide();
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I already considered this, but dropped it but this isn't how a native dropdown (using `<select>`) works. I need that the items menu be closed only when the user **clicks** outside.

Comment: @SNag I don't find anything wrong with it,  in fact,  users would hardly care about closing of a drop-down if focus is outside.  I mean,  a user will either select an option or he won't.  Why would he anyway want to open a list and stray away while keeping the list open till he clicks somewhere else?!!

Comment: @Fr0zenFyr: That's a discussion best had on UX.SE, but for now let's just say that it's just an explicit request from the client -- we had the item-list closable on mouseout, but the client wanted it otherwise, mainly because it was annoying to have the list closed on accidental mouse-outs.

Answer (score 0):

`focus` event is applicable to a limited set of elements, such as form elements (, , etc.) and links ().

Change:

```
<div id="dd_header"></div>
```

to

```
<input type ="text" id="dd_header" />
```

JS:

```
$("#dd_header").focusout(function () {    
    $("#dd_items").hide();
});
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/FLnHG/7/)

Comment: Thanks, but as already noted in the question, this won't help. Clicking on the items-div (to choose an item) immediately closes it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Item 1<br/>
Item 2<br/>
Item 3<br/>
```

This are text and text can not get focus so they can not fire focusout event, You need to have link or control instead of this.[check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FLnHG/)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       $("#dd_items").hide();

       $("#dd_header").click(function () {
          $("#dd_items").show();
       });

       $("#dd_items").mouseleave(function () {
          $("#dd_items").hide();
       });
    });
```

Comment: I already considered `mouseout`/`mouseleave`, but dropped it because I need that the items menu be closed only when the user clicks outside, just as how a native dropdown (using `<select>`) works.

Comment: This also one of the jquery method.try some other methods

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div id="dd_header" tabindex="-1"></div>
<div id="dd_items">
    Item 1<br/>
    Item 2<br/>
    Item 3<br/>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#dd_items").attr('tabindex',-1).focus(function () {

    });

    $(window).focusout(function () {
        $("#dd_items").hide();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm not sure what you exactly want from the question but looking at the comments on other answers,  I came up with a [modification to your own fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ELyQW/16/).

I chose to do it without the use of jQuery.  It's a very simple CSS solution to perhaps what you want.  Only difference if any,  is that the list will toggle on hover(instead of click as in your plan)

Try the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ELyQW/16/) and let us know if it works for you.

**HTML**

```
<div id="dd_header">
    <div id="dd_items">
        <ul style="list-style-type:none;">
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
            <li>Item 3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#dd_header {
    height: 20px; 
    width: 200px; 
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
}

#dd_items {
    display: none; 
    position: absolute; 
    height:200px; 
    width: 200px; 
    background: #fbfbfb;}

#dd_header:hover #dd_items {display: block;}
```